# how to maintain data (item.id) into session before the controller's action call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm constructing some View from controller side, below code shows an "Edit" link in View and on clicking I need to go some different controller's action. As per code I'm keeping my "item.Id" itself in anchor tag.

```
response.Rows =
            (
            from item in selectedListAfterPagging
            select new GridEmployeeData()
            {
                id = item.Id,
                cell = new string[] { 
                item.Id.ToString(),
                item.Name,
                "<a href='/Home/MenuThree/"+ item.Id + "' title='Edit'>Edit</a>"
                }
            }
            ).ToArray();
```

My question, Is there any way to set this data "item.Id" into a Session variable and that will be available to any controller's action?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to use Session when you can pass the id as part of the url which is a far better approach?

Comment: Yes Darin, I did the same way as of now, the reason behind the session is, 1. this data i need to use everywhere (let assume it's a user identity) and 2. i don't want to show my "Id" value in URL, as this is sensitive data, please suggest?

Comment: I suggest you using forms authentication. It is designed exactly for that purpose => track the currently authenticated user in a secure manner without exposing any sensitive information in urls and being accessible everywhere.

Comment: hey, i just giving user identity as a example. In my case, this is not user identity, it's some other sensitive data, please suggest?

Comment: This sensitive data has strictly nothing to do in the view, nor in urls. The place of this sensitive data is on your server (in a database or whatever you are using). I suppose that this data is somehow associated to the user. So once you know the user, you could query your data store to retrieve the sensitive information.

Comment: OK thnx for much info, back to my question Is there a way to kept this data into Session here?

Comment: I don't want to exposes intuitive URL as anyone can manipulate this and get else data...

Answer (score 0):

To write to the session:

```
Session["ItemId"] = item.Id;
```

To read from the session:

```
int ItemId = Session["ItemId"];
```

You can store any valid .NET type in a session variable. Just cast it when you read from the session.

Here is a link that describes in detail ASP.NET sessions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

To solve you problem you might: set your session variable before constructing the view and then when the edit is called you can query the session to see what item id is being edited.